# NodeJS serialport check if port exists function does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-serialport

I have built a Function that check if Port exists via array given from `SerialPort` package.

The port is connected. And when I run the code outside the function it's work(`true` while port's plugged).
When i tried to run it inside a function I recive `undefined`

```
function exists(portName) {
    SerialPort.list(function (err, ports) {
        ports.forEach(function (port) {
            console.log(port.comName);
            if (port.comName == portName) {
                return true
            }
        });
    });
}
console.log(exists('COM7'));
```

results:

```
NodeJS service has started.
undefined
COM1
COM7
Port is connected.
```

Full code at: https://github.com/eshk12/SerialPort-HTTP-Server/blob/master/routes/index.js

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As port checking is *asynchronous* you probably need a promising function:

```
 function exists(portName) {
  return new Promise(res => {
    SerialPort.list((err, ports)=>{
        res(ports.some(port => port.comName === portName));
   });
 });
}
```

Or as @skirtle noted it can be even shorter:

```
const exists = portName => SerialPort.list().then(ports => ports.some(port => port.comName === portName ));
```

So you can do:

```
 exists("CM7").then(res => console.log(res?"exists":"doesnt exist"));
```

Or:

```
(async function(){

   console.log(await exists("CM7"));
})();
```

Comment: `SerialPort.list` also returns a `Promise` so you could chain that rather than creating a new one directly.

Comment: I'm really can't understand how does it work. i'm trying to make it as `if syntax` same as the code i published, all i have succssed to do with that is `console.logged` it

Comment: @itzkb https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: ```function exists(portName) {
    return new Promise(res => {
        SerialPort.list((err, ports)=>{
            PortResults(ports.some(port => port.comName === portName));
        });
    });
}
function PortResults(res){
    return res;
}
console.log(exists(portName));``` I have checked the linked and i tried with the following explainations as you can see. and I recive `Promise { <pending> }`

Comment: @itzikb your code doesnt make sense. Cant you just take over mys?

Comment: it is your code, i would like to use a function that return true/false accordding to the port com's status. for example `isActive() -> true/false` i want to run this function from multiple places and I didnt understand the meaning of all this.

Answer (score 0):

The line `return true` is returning from the anonymous function you've passed to `forEach`, not from your `exist` method.

`SerialPort.list` appears to be asynchronous so you're going to have to use callbacks, promises, etc. rather than relying on returning a value directly from `exist`.